# Multi level array in $_POST with PHP 5.6

Tags: php, arrays, post

I work on a PHP project en post data with an HTML form.
I have an input like this :

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="members[100][active]" />
   <select name="members[100][status]" />
```

I expect to receive this $_POST :

```
   array(
     "members" => array(
       "100" => array(
         "active" => "1",
         "status" => "ABC"
       )
     )
   )
```

It works as expected with PHP 5.3.3 on CentOS6, but not with PHP 5.6.4 on Ubuntu.

Here is the result :

```
   array(
     "members" => array(
       "100" => "active1statusABC"
       )
     )
   )
```

gettype("active1statusABC") return "string", it's defenitely not an array anymore.

On 5.3.3, PHP run with apache, on 5.6.4, I run a standalone PHP server (it's my dev machine with automatic tests)

Is there a php config variable that I have to change ?

EDIT :

values are flattened, too, when using an input name in the forme `name="key[]"`

Comment: should work the same in 5.6. it hasn't changed anything to do with the array-naming fieldname "hack". check your php config and rewrites - perhaps you've got a bad setup there.

Comment: Check what the raw POST data is that your script receives, using `file_get_contents('php://input');` – and then feed that string value into `parse_str`, and see what that gets you.

Comment: Rsult is the same. But the problem seems to be the query string, a ```]``` is lost !

Comment: ```&members%5B100%5D=active1statusABC```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration you are search for may be [`max_input_nesting_level`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-nesting-level).

It is documented as having 64 as default value, and is available since PHP 4.4.8 and PHP 5.2.3. And the configuration entry can be set in `php.ini`, `.htaccess`, `httpd.conf` or `.user.ini` (since PHP 5.3) [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php).

You chould check all of these files.

Comment: phpinfo() say it has the value of 64 in both cases.